# "get into possession" or "come into possession"?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

> If the attacker {comes, gets} into possession of the cryptographic
>   secret, he can do whatever he wants.

Is any of the two possibilities wrong/correct/better or is there even another option?

Comment: _Come_ is often used to indicate change of state; the verbs _come to be_ and _become_ are straightforwardly [inchoative](https://www.google.com/search?q=inchoative). And _get_ is the inchoative of both _be_ and _have_ (_I got/am tired; I got/have a new car_). So it's inevitable that _come_ and _get_ are mixed up in a mess of constructions from which it is hard to extract one but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwhelmingly, "come" (and its inflections) is used here.

I searched the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for `_v* into possession of` (where `_v*` matches verbs) and got the following results:

> - come into possession of: 34 hits

- came into possession of: 21 hits
- comes into possession of: 5 hits
- coming into possession of: 2 hits
- put into possession of: 1 hit
- lucked into possession of: 1 hit

Note: Even after looking at the hit itself, I'm really not sure what to make of "put" in this context. As a native speaker of American English, I can't say I ever remember hearing it used like this.

On the other hand, "lucked" here is perfectly idiomatic to me (albeit informal), but it means not only did you *come* into possession of something, you were also lucky to do so. Therefore, it's not really a synonym.